# Angular 7 injected service being unset

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular7

I'm doing a simple injection of a service into my component via the constructor.  In both `constructor` and `ngOnInit` I print out the value and I see it's an object, as expected.  In the `ngOnInit` I'm doing a `valueChanges` subscription like so:

```js
constructor(private readonly detailService: DetailService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.updateHazardClassificationSingleton();

  this.thisTabFormGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
  ).subscribe(this.updateHazardClassificationSingleton);
}

private updateHazardClassificationSingleton(): void {
    this.detailService.setHazardClassification(this.hazardClassification);
    this.detailService.setHazardClassificationIsSet(this.hazardClassificationIsSet);
}
```

When the `updateHazardClassificationSingleton` method runs manually the injected service is there with a value.  When it runs via the subscription, the injected service is `undefined`.  There's nothing in my code that sets the injected object's value directly.  How could it be going undefined?

Detail service is provided in root.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DetailService {
```

Comment: You should double check what `this` is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is because `this` context

instead of;

`subscribe(this.updateHazardClassificationSingleton)`

try;

`subscribe(this.updateHazardClassificationSingleton.bind(this))`

Comment: Thanks.  `this` definitely wasn't binding because of the way I passed it.